# multiple c# windows form application

Tags: c#

I have two forms, the main form and a form named FrmSteg. I added a button on the main form and entered the code below in the click event of the button.But i got an error "Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement"

```
private void btnsteg_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FrmSteg newForm = new FrmSteg();
    newForm.Show;
    this.Hide; 
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
newForm.Show();
this.Hide();
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the `()` behind the method call:

```
newForm.Show();
this.Hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

If the new form is supposed to be used as kind of a dialog, use `ShowDialogue(newForm);`
This will "lock" your main form until the new form has been closed.